# dynamically generate list of beans from .yaml file in confg-server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm using spring-config-server. I have it working, but Ideally, I'd like to generate a list of servers in a .yaml file that have properties.

```
@Resource
private List<Server> servers;
```

then:

```
@Component
public class Server {

      @Value("${server.name}")
       private String name;
}
```

in the (applicationName).yaml file:

```
servers:
-
    name: test
-
    name: test2
```

See I want a `List<Server>` generated dynamically from a config. The fact that this config is on a config server shouldn't be that different from a local .yaml file right?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you need the ‘Server` instances to be `@Components`? It looks like you should just be able to inject them using a `Converter` or a `PropertEditor`.

Comment: I don't know. Honestly, I'm pretty new to spring. If someone could point me to a good example? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: The fact that it is coming from config server should have no bearing on spring boot parsing the configuration, though you'll need to change your yaml and java to get what you are looking for.

Comment: I've gotten a littler farther, I know my yaml needs to look like (I edited above, I can't get comment to format).

Answer (score 3):

we figured this out...

```
Trinity:
  test: Goober
  servers:
    -
      name: test
      jmxURL: jmx://test
    -
      name: test2
      jmxURL: jmx://test
```

that's the config (in config server)... this is the code

```
@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="Trinity")
public class ConfigFetcher {


    List<Server> servers;

    public List<Server> getServers() {
        return servers;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }


    public void setServers(List<Server> servers) {
        this.servers = servers;
    }


    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="Trinity.servers")
    public static class Server{
        private String name;
        private String jmxURL;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public String getJmxURL() {
            return jmxURL;
        }

        public void setJmxURL(String jmxURL) {
            this.jmxURL = jmxURL;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Server [name=" + name + ", jmxUrl=" + jmxURL + "]";
        }

    }   

}
```

in the main class (in my service in this case):
with the class having the following annotation

```
 @EnableAutoConfiguration


    @Autowired
    private ConfigFetcher c;
```